# Google Cloud Storage - PUT Fails on Development Server

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

On my dev server, Google Cloud Storage fails to save files during a `PUT` command.

This same command works fine on production. The response headers (see below) have little debug information. I have plenty of space on my hard-drive, and I have been running the dev server as an administrator, so it should have all necessary permissions.

Any ideas?

Below is the relevant Traceback (I changed the bucket name):

```
INFO     2015-08-07 14:14:41,415 module.py:809] default: "PUT /_ah/gcs/bucket/IPR2013-00219%2C%20No.%2016%20Institution%20Decision%20-%20Decis_2015-08-07%2018-14-25.100000.pdf?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AZG9ja2V0YWxhcm0tZGV2L0lQUjIwMTMtMDAyMTksIE5vLiAxNiBJbnN0aXR1dGlvbiBEZWNpc2lvbiAtIERlY2lzXzIwMTUtMDgtMDcgMTgtMTQtMjUuMTAwMDAwLnBkZg%3D%3D HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project\libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 794, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "Project\libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 787, in close
    self._flush(finish=True)
  File "Project\libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 841, in _flush
    self._send_data(data, self._written, file_len)
  File "Project\libs\cloudstorage\storage_api.py", line 874, in _send_data
    {'upload_path': self._path_with_token})
  File "Project\libs\cloudstorage\errors.py", line 141, in check_status
    raise ServerError(msg)
ServerError: Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 500.
Path: '/bucket/IPR2013-00219%2C%20No.%2016%20Institution%20Decision%20-%20Decis_2015-08-07%2018-14-25.100000.pdf'.
Request headers: {'accept-encoding': 'gzip, *', 'content-range': 'bytes 0-195060/195061', 'x-goog-api-version': '2'}.
Response headers: {'date': 'Fri, 07 Aug 2015 18:14:41 GMT', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'Development/2.0'}.
Body: ''.
Extra info: {'upload_path': '/bucket/IPR2013-00219%2C%20No.%2016%20Institution%20Decision%20-%20Decis_2015-08-07%2018-14-25.100000.pdf?upload_id=encoded_gs_file%3AZG9ja2V0YWxhcm0tZGV2L0lQUjIw
MTMtMDAyMTksIE5vLiAxNiBJbnN0aXR1dGlvbiBEZWNpc2lvbiAtIERlY2lzXzIwMTUtMDgtMDcgMTgtMTQtMjUuMTAwMDAwLnBkZg%3D%3D'}.
```

**Update 2020**
FYI, I raised this [issue with Google here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900575), and they said that they won't fix it because it has already been fixed, even though it clearly has not.

**Update 2022**
Still broken! See the proposed patch in the [issue with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900575).

Comment: I'm getting this same error. Tried upgrading App Engine to 1.9.30 (from 1.9.25 or so) and upgrading the python lib GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient (to 1.9.22). No luck. Wonder if this could be related: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10996. FWIW, the storage command works on the deployed server, just not on the dev server.

Comment: I debugged this issue, and it is indeed a bug with the SDK. See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12976. In that issue report, I've outlined a way you can monkey-patch the SDK to work correctly. Please star that issue request so it gets Google's attention.

Comment: Just to given you some ideas: security permissions? server misconfiguration? server capacity? what are the dependencies that maybe you don't have on the dev? Try with a smaller file also.

Comment: Did you add this to your code? 


import os
import mock
import google.auth.credentials


os.environ["DATASTORE_DATASET"] = "test"
os.environ["DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1:8001"
os.environ["DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH"] = "127.0.0.1:8001/datastore"
os.environ["DATASTORE_HOST"] = "http://127.0.0.1:8001"
os.environ["DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID"] = "test"

credentials = mock.Mock(spec=google.auth.credentials.Credentials)
db = ndb.Client(project="test", credentials=credentials)

Comment: I find it worrying that the target path includes spaces (not a brilliant idea) encoded as `%20` and a comma encoded as `%2C` _(**almost never** a good idea)_. It is possible that the dev server isn't sanitising these.

Comment: So you are trying to send to a file called `/bucket/IPR2013-00219, No. 16 Institution Decision - Decis_2015-08-07 2018-14-25.100000.pdf` which is being rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the correct permissions to access the bucket. You can check this by running the following command:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket/
```

If you do not have the correct permissions, you will need to contact your Google Cloud Storage administrator to grant you the necessary permissions.

Also, make sure that the bucket exists. You can check this by running the following command:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket/
```

Make sure that you are using the correct API version. The API version that you are using may not be supported on your dev server.